# The body of scholarship on... Can it be a type of library or catalogue?

Tags: meaning

> The fund also launched what soon became a respected publication in the
> field, The Journal of Air Law […] This added to **the body of
> scholarship on** aviation Harry and the directors sought to build
> through the **commissioning of technical papers, lectures, and
> conferences** on a huge range of aeronautical subjects.

Actually, a have two separate questions about this fragment, but they seem to be somehow interconnected.

1. **The body of scholarship on**.
   While Google gives numerous search results, I can’t find a proper entry in classic dictionaries. My guess is that it’s a collection of research, scientific etc. materials, sort of a library, but I’m not sure.
2. **Commissioning of lectures and conferences.**
   If my guess in the previous question is correct, then it seems “lectures and conferences” means the “texts of lectures, and materials from conferences.” If my guess was wrong, then it may well be that they organized and/or held such lectures or conferences.

Please help me understand.

Comment: 1 - Such a body is metaphorical rather than a fixed library. 2 - The commissioning is the booking of those items, not the resulting books.

Comment: Yes, 1 – the generally known material. 2 – the latter: they organise or more probably *pay an event manager* to do it.

Comment: The terms "body of scholarship", "body of literature", and the like are variant ways of describing the extant expert (scholarly) knowledge in a field. 
 See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_of_knowledge